# How can custom keycloak error message in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm newbie on node, I have a rest api with express and some endpoint are with keycloak security using keycloak-connect. I need a custom response when error 403 ocurrs, ie custom message in json format. I use a handler to managed some other status like, 200, 201, 204, 404, 500, but I could not do works when keycloak throws a 403.

```
var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'my-secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

var keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
});

app.use(keycloak.middleware());

// keycloak security
app.get('/service/secured', keycloak.protect('realm:user'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'secured'});
});

app.get('/service/admin', keycloak.protect('realm:admin'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'admin'});
});

// 404 handler and pass to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {    
    next(createError(404, 'Not found'));
});

// Error Handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => { 
    // This log never is printed when 403 ocurrs
    console.log('Error: ', err); 
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
        error : {
            status : err.status || 500,
            message : err.message
        }
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server starter on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is keycloak-connect uses express middleware wrong. It uses `res.end()` instead `next()` so you can do nothing after this. You can try to rewrite this logic by adding new middleware.

```
...

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.end = function(body) {
    if (res.statusCode === 403 && body === 'Access denied') {
      next(body);
    } else {
      res.send(body);
    }
  }
});

app.use(keycloak.middleware());

...

// handle error how you want
```

Comment: The request just timeout. How do i return a custom response object instead of the default `Access denied` text

Comment: @odane-brissett
Do you have a router error handler?
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Like this:

`app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can override `Keycloak.prototype.accessDenied` before initialization and throw new error so your handle can treat.

```
var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'my-secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: memoryStore
}));

// Overriding keycloak access denied to return 401 status code and custom message.
Keycloak.prototype.accessDenied = () => {
  // Considering createError will throw new Error.
  createError(401, 'Access Denied');
};

var keycloak = new Keycloak({
  store: memoryStore
});

app.use(keycloak.middleware());

// keycloak security
app.get('/service/secured', keycloak.protect('realm:user'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'secured'});
});

app.get('/service/admin', keycloak.protect('realm:admin'), function (req, res) {
  res.json({message: 'admin'});
});

// 404 handler and pass to error handler
app.use((req, res, next) => {    
    next(createError(404, 'Not found'));
});

// Error Handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => { 
    // Now this print with error 401 and message Access Denied
    console.log('Error: ', err); 
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
        error : {
            status : err.status || 500,
            message : err.message
        }
    });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server starter on port ${PORT}`);
});
```